# Octave - critical error. Installation on linux mint

Tags: ubuntu, octave, linux-mint

I tried installing Octave on my Linux Mint machine. Firstly it stopped mid download when I tried to install it with the software manager. I then tried installing it with the terminal using the following commands:

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install octave

But when I open Octave it gives the following error:

The settings file /home/user/.config/octave/qt-settings
does not exist and can not be created.
Make sure you have read and write permissions to
/home/user/.config/octave

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you

Comment: have you followed the advice in the message?

Comment: I am new to linux (and quite a lot of computer related things) so that is why I am struggling a bit. But I found a solution - I just had to change the permissions with the "sudo chmod -R ugo+rw  /home/user/.config/octave" command. Turns out error messages are quite helpful. Feeling like a real noob now. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Quite simple in fact. You only have to change the permissions with the following command:

sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /home/user/.config/octave

Comment: `sudo chmod -R ugo+rw` is generally a bad idea. This enables read and write access to everyone. Have you checked the access settings before changing them? And yeah, error messages on GNU/Linux are ment to be helpful and should lead you into the right direction

Comment: Is it possible that you have run Octave with `sudo octave` for the very first time?

Comment: I don't think the 'sudo chmod -R ugo+rw' can be such a problem seeing as I am the only one using this machine and I am just playing around with maths and coding. Or is there something that I do not understand? I do not think I have run Octave with the sudo command for the first time. I just tried to run it by clicking on the icon.